# How to rotate a vector in 3d space according to a tangent vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I need to rotate a (unit) vector **a** at a known angle **γ** relative to a rotation axis in 3d space. Vector **a** points from the origin to a point that is located on a unit circle where its origin is the same as the world space and it *"sits"* in the *xy plane* of the coordinate space, as illustrated bellow:

[image]

My knowledge on mathematics is super limited but it's not hard to visualize the fact that I could rotate the vector **a** at a known angle around the rotation axis (drawn in blue) which looks like the tangent of the circle where vector **a** points.

1. How do I find the rotation axis?
2. How do I make the rotation?

An example demonstrating that process would be quite helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axis of rotation is $\mathbf{a}$ rotated by 90 degrees about the z axis.  This is $(-a_y, a_x, 0)$.  To rotate $\mathbf{a}$ about the axis of rotation, use [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula).